# Is there an equivalent of sbrk(0) on Windows

Tags: c, windows, memory-management

I use sbrk(0) to monitor usage of dynamic memory from within an application. At the beginning of the program I do

dynamic_base = sbrk(0);

and a various points through the program use

sbrk(0) - dynamic_base

as a measure of the current high water mark of memory usage. Is there an equivalent for Windows?

Alternatively, are there better ways of determining dynamic memory usage from within a process for both Windows and Unix.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: [Memory Performance Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965225.aspx). Make sure you read all of [About Memory Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366525.aspx) to make educated decisions on which figures to gather.

Comment: I would also add a Linux or Unix tag, since the question is also about them...

Answer (score 1):

VirtualAlloc is the rough equivalent in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The performance counters suggested by IInspectable will work, but they're somewhat complex.

If all you want to know is the amount of memory your application is using, call `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` and check the `ullTotalVirtual` and `ullAvailVirtual` members of the result.

Unlike the `sbrk` method, this doesn't distinguish between statically loaded code and data sections, dynamically loaded modules, thread stacks, and dynamic allocations (heap).  But *differences* in this number will be differences in maximum heap size.

Comment: `ullAvailVirtual` does not include uncommitted, reserved memory. This memory is essentially unused by the application. Since the heap manager of the CRT that ships with Visual Studio never returns uncommitted memory to the OS but rather keeps it reserved, measuring `ullAvailVirtual` will report a value that's consistently lower than the amount of memory available to the application. In practice it is of very little use, with the exception of memory leak detection.

Comment: @IInspectable: True, but that still is using up virtual address space... and the discrepancy will be large only if the application uses VirtualAlloc to reserve pages without committing.  In that respect it acts a lot like the `sbrk` as requested.

Comment: This is precisely what the CRT does: It will not release any memory that has ever been requested by the application, until the process terminates. When an application returns memory to the CRT's memory manager, it will merely uncommit the memory. The memory will remain reserved. Consequently, the `ullAvailVirtual` figure will generally be a bad measure if you are interested in an application's memory pressure.

Comment: I thought it remains committed too, and added on the heap free list

Comment: You are right, the default heap manager doesn't uncommit memory, but rather leaves it committed and internally manages free regions. The effect remains the same, though: Memory reported as *used* by a call to `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` includes *free* memory from the heap manager's perspective. `ullAvailVirtual` will not account for the heap manager's internal state, and will usually not answer the question of how much memory an application uses.

Comment: @IInspectable: Ahh, but the question asks about the high water mark, not the currently allocated bytes.  And pages owned by the heap manager, whether currently in use or on the free list, give a good estimate of that high water mark.

Comment: That's true. I was mislead by the term *monitor usage of dynamic memory* in the question to mean *currently used memory by the application*. The question does explicitly state *high water mark*, though, and your answer fully addresses that. Whether or not this figure is an appropriate diagnostic value is questionable. Irrespective of that, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`sbrk` is obsolete, even on Linux (e.g. because not multi-thread friendly). Several malloc implementations are only using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (and most of them sometimes use `mmap` at least for large enough `malloc`-s).

> are there better ways of determining dynamic memory usage from within a process on Linux?

<sup>(I'm skipping the Windows part of the question)</sup>

On Linux you could (and you'll better) use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to query your memory usage. In particular, reading (these are sequential pseudo-files, a bit like pipes) `/proc/self/stat`, `/proc/self/maps`, `/proc/self/statm` etc. For example, `fopen` them, `fscanf` them, `fclose` them quickly. There is no real disk IO involved, since these pseudo files have their contents synthesized by the kernel on demand.

And there is also [mallinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html) or [malloc_stats(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html), at least for *some* implementations of `malloc` on Linux.

Comment: Ok, sbrk is obsolete. So you do you mmap() on Windows ?? Does it also has a syscall called "mmap"?

Comment: I never used Windows. I don't know if it has `mmap` (probably not natively). Perhaps the latest "bash/ubuntu on Windows10" might be a sort-of Linux personality providing some emulation of Linux system calls, I really don't know.